# Помогите с задачей, у меня какая-то ошибка

Tags: алгоритм, память

> Петя сконструировал устройство, состоящее из датчика и памяти. Датчик снимает показания в диапазоне от 0 до 1 с точностью 0.1 и сохраняет в памяти каждое значение отдельно. В память можно записать только целое количество байт, поэтому каждое показание датчика занимает ровно 1 байт. Вася предложил добавить в устройство буфер, накапливающий N показаний. Как только буфер полностью заполняется, получившаяся комбинация показаний кодируется минимально возможным количеством бит и записывается в память, занимая целое количество байт. При каком минимальном размере буфера, объем информации, записанный после его заполнения, окажется на 10 байт меньше, чем заняла бы запись такого же количества показаний при отсутствии буфера? В ответе укажите целое число – размер буфера, определенный как количество показаний датчика, которые можно в нем накопить.

У меня получается уравнение N = 10 + (log2(4*n)) / 8, где
N - кол-во байт без буфера;
n = N - кол-во показаний, размер буфера;
4 - кол-во бит для одного показания;

```
4 = log2 11;
11:
0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 ... 0.9 1.0
```

но получается неправильный ответ

Comment: @Clarkkent, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @Free_ze в конце же написано, что я сделал, и что не получилось